# How can I partially fill a numpy array with a value given a range?

Tags: python, numpy

Given a numpy array, a range, and a value, how can I fill the array with the value inside the range?

Is there a way that is faster than filling it in manually with a loop one by one?

**Edit:**

`myArray = np.zeros(10)`

What I want:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: This is a little unclear. you can do `array[range]=value` if i understand you correctly. Otherwise post what you have and what you expect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr = np.zeros(10)
arr[4:7] = 1
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.])
```